# Force OS to Send TCP Message

Tags: tcp, network-programming, centos6, glibc

I wonder whether there is a way to force the OS to send TCP messages as soon as send() is called.

I have already turned on TCP_NODELAY but according to tcpdump, I can see some messages are merged into 1 packet (e.g. I saw a 7K byte packet although each of my messages was only 186 bytes).  It seems like the OS/NIC can't keep up and so somewhere buffers the messages.

I also checked TCP_MAXSEG was set to 536 by default.  So it seems like TCP_MAXSEG is ignored?

I am looking for a solution to tell the OS not to send a huge packet.  If OS/NIC can't keep up, OS should send multiple packets based on the max size I specify (somehow?).

Any input is welcome.

Comment: try to set TCP_CORK to 0

Comment: Right, I see that option.  It does solve my problem but creates another -- system call, which will cause some latency, which I am trying to reduce...thanks for your suggestion tho :)